# Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver - chromedriver.exe is not being publishing for netcore2.2 target framework

Tags: c#, .net-core, selenium-chromedriver

I installed nuget package - Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver 2.46.0.. When I publish (through dotnet publish .Net CLI command) .csproject (target framework - netcore2.2) the chromedriver.exe is not being copying on output/publish folder.. Can you please someone assist me?

Comment: Right click your file, and select properties. Select Copy to output directory: Always.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

From the project owner [github](https://github.com/jsakamoto/nupkg-selenium-webdriver-chromedriver/) page:

"chromedriver(.exe)" isn't included in published files on default configuration. This behavior is by design.

If you want to include "chromedriver(.exe)" into published files, please define `_PUBLISH_CHROMEDRIVER` compilation symbol.

[image]

**OR**

Define `PublishChromeDriver` property with value to "true" in MSBuild file (.csproj, .vbproj, etc...) to publish the driver file.

```
<Project ...>
    ...
    <PropertyGroup>
      ...
      <PublishChromeDriver>true</PublishChromeDriver>
      ...
    </PropertyGroup>
...
</Project>
```

Note: MSBuild property always override the condition of define `_PUBLISH_CHROMEDRIVER` compilation symbol